# What option we can disable temporary in PostgreSQL make database update faster

Tags: postgresql, update, logging

I want to update 3 million records within some seconds. i have tried doing below things

```
ALTER TABLE imagingresourceplanning.opnav_fact_revenue_costs SET UNLOGGED ;    
ALTER TABLE imagingresourceplanning.opnav_fact_revenue_costs DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

once the update is done i am reverting this settings. with this change i have noticed that my update time is now 2 minutes which was eariler taking 10 min.

What other settings i can disable in PostgreSQL to make update even more faster. Data in my table is inserted and update by nightly job.

My postgresql version is 9.5

Thanks

Comment: Note the risks in what you're doing. You cannot have a valid backup set that will allow an emergency restore including the updated data (fixable as soon as you can run a full backup). Similarly, any activity performed by the triggers will not be performed. You should look at the changes you're making and what the triggers do, to make sure that the trigger code is really unneeded here.. If some (but not all) of it is necessary, you can try to incorporate it into your update code.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL maintains a list of optimizations you could make, all of which come at a cost of durability over time.

- [Non-Durable Settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/non-durability.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to increase your update speed by "disabling" foreign keys check as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38113838/3783432).

Comment: That assumes that user2274074 is actually updating a FK column